# Error with Spring and quartz

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am getting below error .I noticed quartz-all-1.6.1.jar/ Scheduler interface doesn't have this method. Any idea how to fix it?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.quartz.Scheduler.getListenerManager()Lorg/quartz/ListenerManager
```

Comment: post pom.xml helps

Comment: Not feasible  to paste pom here but start getting this error when I did below steps.       I can create bean of <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean"> with spring-context 3.1.2 but getting error when we switch springcontect version to 4.3.9

Answer (score 1):

This is usually because your quartz version is too old, try [upgrade to last version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: below error i m getting looks like i need to make changes in code as well as part of upgrading of spring version Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean has interface org.quartz.JobDetail as super class

Comment: @spandey15 Seems like you need update your code since the quartz API has changed. This helps. https://www.mkyong.com/spring/incompatibleclasschangeerror-jobdetailbean-has-interface-org-quartz-jobdetail-as-super-class/

Comment: @spandey15 no problem, may be you can accept the answer if it solved the problem :)